# Server Response dosn't match dataBase rows in a HTTP GET Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, get

So I am working with JavaSpring boot for a web app , and mySql for the DB , the concerned table in the database is named contient as you can see in the picture the SELECT * SQL query : [image: image showing the result of the SELECT * FROM contient]
[image]

when I send a HTTP get request in POSTMAN here is the response : [image: image showing the postman get result]

jumping to the code :
I have a Controller handling the request named ContientController :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contient")
public class ContientController {

    private final ContientService contientService;

    public ContientController(ContientService contientService) {
        this.contientService = contientService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contient>> getAllContient(){
        List<Contient> contients = contientService.findAllContient();
        return new  ResponseEntity<>(contients, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and as you can see it's calling the Service named contientService , and here is the code :

```
@Service
public class ContientService {

    private final ContientRepo contientRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ContientService(ContientRepo contientRepo) {
        this.contientRepo = contientRepo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Contient> findAllContient(){
        return contientRepo.getAllContient();
    }
```

the Service is calling the Repository which contains the method defining the SQL query :

```
public interface ContientRepo extends JpaRepository<Contient,Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM contient",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Contient> getAllContient();
}
```

and finally the Contient module :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contient")
public class Contient {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_commande")
    private Long id_commande;

    @Column(name="id_produit")
    private Long id_produit;

    @Column(name="qte_produit")
    private int qte_produit;

// constructor and getters and setters 
}
```

I really tried to debug it , I looked it up on the internet I didn't find a similar questions/solution , tried chatGPT also and it didn't give me an answer ,

Comment: you need to make a composite key https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with primary key in your entity. You define id_commande as the primary key but in your database, this field has the same value for the 3 rows. You probably want a composite key with id_commande and id_produit.